# Нужно чтобы при нажатии на ту же кнопку div появлялся и снова исчезал

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Я сделал так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку div появлялся, нужно сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии он исчезал. Нужно сделать на чистом JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="check2.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function viewdiv(){
          document.getElementById("notewrite").style.display = "table";
        };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value="+" class="btn_add" onclick="viewdiv()">
      <div class="notewrite" id="notewrite">
          <form method="post">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Введите заголовок"><br>
          <textarea placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea><br>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
#notewrite{
    display:none
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function viewdiv() {
  document.getElementById("notewrite").classList.toggle('toggle');
};
```

```css
#notewrite {
  display: none
}

#notewrite.toggle {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn_add" onclick="viewdiv()">
<div class="notewrite" id="notewrite">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите заголовок"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea><br>
   </form>
</div>
```